# How to retrieve stored data on firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

Recently firebase made some changes in SDK Setup & Configuration. Now I'm not able to access data with new SDK.

earlier I was using this sytax... in firebase.config.js file

```
 import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
 import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
 import 'firebase/compat/auth';

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
 var firebaseConfig = {
     apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     projectId: "xxxxx",
     storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
     messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxx"
   };

 const firebaseApp=firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 const db=firebase.firestore();

 export default {db};
```

=========================================

and this is how I was consuming data.... in Homepage.js file

```
const fetchBlogs=async()=>{
      const response=db.collection('blogs');
      const data=await response.get();
      console.log(data);
      data.docs.forEach(item=>{
         .....
.........in the ***item*** variable, I was getting all the required data... now it's gone...........
...................

        })
}
```

Comment: Not aware of anything in that changed for this but remove the .docs part of your foreach and just do data.forEach - Reference to documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection

Comment: Okay, thanks! but Now their SDK is like this: 

`import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "==================",
  authDomain: "=============",
  projectId: "===========",
  storageBucket: "==========",
  messagingSenderId: "===========",
  appId: "1:"==============",
  measurementId: "========"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);`
so wrt this configs, how to use the respective fetch data functions... not aware.

Comment: That is the modular approach of Web version 9, see here for an example of Web version 8  which you are using https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-version-8_7 It is recommended to update to SDK 9, you can read through the documentation on how to do so